# How can I only show the custom error message for Python's unittest module

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertion

Using Python's `unittest` module, the assertion

```
self.assertTrue(a > b - 0.5 && a < b + 0.5, "The two values did not agree")
```

outputs the following on failure:

```
AssertionError: False is not true : The two values did not agree
```

I don't want the `False is not true` to be printed. Ideally, `AssertionError` shouldn't be printed either. Only `The two values did not agree` should be printed.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supress the `False is true` part, however, one thing to keep in mind here, you are *raising* an exception, and what you are seeing is the standard output of an assertion being raised in Python. You want to see this. Furthermore, this is being called directly in the assertion methods, as you can see from the `assertTrue` below:

```
def assertTrue(self, expr, msg=None):
    """Check that the expression is true."""
    if not expr:
        msg = self._formatMessage(msg, "%s is not true" % safe_repr(expr))
        raise self.failureException(msg)
```

To supress the 'False is true' part, change the [longMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.longMessage) class attribute to False:

```
class TestCompare(unittest.TestCase):

    longMessage = False

    def test_thing(self):
        self.assertTrue(5 == 6, "The two values did not agree")
```

Output:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXX/dev/rough/test_this.py", line 21, in test_things
    self.assertTrue(5 == 6, "The two values did not agree")
AssertionError: The two values did not agree
```

Comment: @Tyler No problem. Good luck.